# multiple inheritance execution order

Tags: python, python-2.x

code1：

```
class base(object):
    def test(self):
        pass


class low1(object):
    def test(self):
        super(low1, self).test()
        print "low1 test"


class low2(object):
    def test(self):
        super(low2, self).test()
        print "low2 test"


class high(low1, low2, base):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    high().test()
```

code2：

```
class base(object):
    def test(self):
        pass


class low1(object):
    def test(self):
        # super(low1, self).test()
        print "low1 test"


class low2(object):
    def test(self):
        # super(low2, self).test()
        print "low2 test"


class high(low1, low2, base):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    high().test()
```

the output of code1 is：

```
low2 test
low1 test
```

the output of code2 is：

```
low1 test
```

when I call why test method of a high object， it execute test method of both low1 and low2？

Comment: You called `super(low2...` in code1.  If you are going to use `super` please [learn to understand how they work and why you might use them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods).

Comment: I just added the "Python 2" tag to the question. The reason is that the behaviour of inheritance and `super()` changed a bit between Python 2 and Python 3. BTW: If you're learning Python, don't start with Python 2 but use the current version 3 from the start, it offers quite a few advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the method resolution order:

```
print(high.mro())
```

This prints:

```
[<class '__main__.high'>, <class '__main__.low1'>, <class '__main__.low2'>,
 <class '__main__.base'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Think of `super()` meaning "next in line", where line is the list of classes shown above. Therefore, `super(low1, self)` finds `low2` as the class next in line.